Can I install Ubuntu as the only OS on a new Windows 11 pc without first setting up Windows?
I have bought a cheap new PC which I hope to put Ubuntu 24.04 or an official flavor as a sole operating system. The PC is an Acer XC-840 manufactured in September 2022 and still in box unused. Spec Intel N4505 processor ,4GB DDr4 Ram, 256 GB SSD , Intel UHD graphics , Bios R01-A2 . Hopefully this is able to run Ubuntu . I have never installed on other than very old computers and would like to know what I need to do to avoid failure . Do I need to run Windows first or can I Boot from a USB with Ubuntu ISO on and just select install using whole drive without disabling secure boot or making other changes beforehand ? As is probably obvious I am very much a beginner with Linux and would appreciate any available guidance.

I cannot find the answer on the site at the moment, but you can always download the ISO of Ubuntu and boot it to Try where you can test if it will work or not with your hardware before you go and wipe anything out.

You don't need to install Windows first. Just boot the Ubuntu ISO and install it

You should be aware that at the time of writing, Ubuntu 24.04 is still in beta. It's not uncommon to experience minor user experience issues running beta versions of Ubuntu. The final (24.04.0) release will be on the 25th of April 2024.

To answer the question in the subject line:
Yes, as long as you already have a bootable media. On Acer computers, the F12 key during system initialization will give you a boot menu from which you can select your bootable media. Then, you can Try Ubuntu before you install it to ensure everything works with your hardware.
If you don't have a bootable media, and no other computer from which to create one, you can use your Windows 11 installation to create it. Setup the Windows11 OS minimally, including an Internet capable network connection. Then, follow the instructions to create the media.
During installation, you will be given the option Erase disk and install Ubuntu to reclaim all your drive space for a clean and full use of your storage by the Ubuntu OS.

I'll report here part of Rinzwind's original (now deleted) answer, as it's something I very often stumble upon when running Ubuntu from a live USB on modern hardware: "I have seen BIOS where you needed to alter the Advanced Host Controller Interface to AHCI instead of IDE" -> I think Rinzwind actually meant to suggest to switch the SATA operation mode of the (NVME) drive from RAID to AHCI -> this is absolutley true as having the SATA operation mode set to RAID impacts Ubuntu's ability to see the destination drive during install - something to keep in mind.

@kos if I am not mistaken, that would be Intel RST (which Ubuntu setup should warn about), recently renamed to (replaced by?) VMD on new chips, which is sometimes unnecessarily enabled on mass produced machines with preinstalled Windows. Annoying thing that also blocks clean Windows installation.
Neither RST nor VMD should not be available on N series CPU.

@PTwr You're correct, they're the same thing, however I never knew the installer would warn about this (swift move as IIRC you don't get the same warning when installing Windows 10, not sure about 11, which has left me puzzled a few times :|)

@kos Ubuntu is supposed to show message linking to https://help.ubuntu.com/rst/ but I do not know if it detects VMD.

@PTwr BTW do you know if changing SATA operation mode cause an integrity check failure when trying to fetch a BitLocker key from the TPM? If that's the case, there should be a giant warning on the guide... I've known this at some point, but I can't remember.
